# setting the security slider to medium

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, settings

It says that setting the security slider of the torbrowser to medium disables the function which is dangerous. I would like to know what features are considered dangerous and why.

And if I set the security slider to medium, I can disable dangerous functions, so is it safe to browse with medium setting?

Comment: Whether it's safe to browse with medium certainly depends on who you're hiding from and how much heat you're dealing with. Would you want to handle government secrets with mere "medium" let alone any kind of default setting? Certainly not!

Answer (score 1):

The default setting provides you with a good trade-off between security and usability. When you switch to medium several HTML5 and JavaScript features don't work instantly or don't work at all.

So for HTML5 video and audio you need to click on them to start them. So in theory you can review where those files are loaded and if they're malware they're not executed instantly. Furthermore JavaScript only works with HTTPS sites and JavaScript on HTTP sites is disabled.

I use the medium setting for the day-to-day browsing and from my experience this works well. However I cannot measure if I get more security out of it.

The highest security setting would be to set it to Safest. Because here is most JavaScript disabled and JavaScript can be dangerous. However I bet most of the sites won't work properly anymore.

Comment: Paradoxically, I find that medium provides a _better_ browsing experience than the default, simply because obnoxious autoplay videos and ads are less prevalent. Safest is even better still since virtually _no_ ads are shown, but it does indeed break some sites.